# Why did the monk take a boat, when he could just have jumped over the river?

Tags: plot-explanation, sorcerer-and-white-snake

In the movie ["The Sorcerer and the White Snake"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1857913/), the monk and his disciple need to cross a river. They call a nearby apothecary in his boat, and politely ask for passage, to which the apothecary gladly complies.

Later it is shown that both the monk and the disciple could jump really far, each leap spanning more than the breadth of the river.

Why would the monk and his disciple wait for the boat instead of just jumping over the river?

Comment: I have not watched the movie but monks should not show off their super powers in public. Therefore, they may have used the boat to cross the river in public but used their super powers to jump the river in private.